# Active Directory Integration issue Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory

I am new with Node js and I want to make Authentication with Azure Active Directory. I Downloaded Node and Installed NPM as mentioned [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devquickstarts-openidconnect-nodejs)

```
npm install express
npm install ejs
npm install ejs-locals
npm install restify
npm install mongoose
npm install bunyan
npm install assert-plus
npm install passport
npm install passport-azure-ad
```

after that as per document, I  followed **Step 3: Set up your app to use the passport-node-js strategy**

Here is *config.js*

```
exports.creds = {
    returnURL: 'https://hpe.onmicrosoft.com/8d332647-xxxx-4xxc-8xx-11776XXXXX',
    identityMetadata: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com', // For using Microsoft you should never need to change this.
    clientID: '22XXXX9-b5fa-XXXXb-bc7a-XXXXXXXa92a',
    clientSecret: 'Srekv8dM1NqP4Sqnxxxxxxxxxxxx', // if you are doing code or id_token code
    skipUserProfile: true, // for AzureAD should be set to true.
    responseType: 'id_token code', // for login only flows use id_token. For accessing resources use `id_token code`
    responseMode: 'query', // For login only flows we should have token passed back to us in a POST
    //scope: ['email', 'profile'] // additional scopes you may wish to pass
 };
```

and rest of code i have written as mentioned in document.

But when I run app.js am getting issues.

```
C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-skeleton\node_modules\passport-azure-ad\lib\validator.js:51
      throw new TypeError(`Invalid value for ${item}.${checker.error}`);
      ^

TypeError: Invalid value for redirectUrl.The URL must be valid and be https://
    at Object.keys.forEach (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-skeleton\node_modules\passport-azure-ad\lib\validator.js:51:13)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Validator.validate (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-skeleton\node_modules\passport-azure-ad\lib\validator.js:37:28)
    at new Strategy (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-skeleton\node_modules\passport-azure-ad\lib\oidcstrategy.js:495:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-skeleton\app.js:42:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Please help me..

Regards
Nikunj

**Try 1 :** 
I tried Nan yu 's suggested code and I got error :

```
(node:2628) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client

events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-master\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:329:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-master\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:318:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active Directory\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS-master\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:187:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:316:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:62:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:102:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:161:9)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to code sample : [Azure Active Directory OIDC Web Sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS)

The redirect url should match the reply URL registered in AAD for your app . In that document , it is `http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return`

**Update**

To make code sample https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS work ,please refer to below steps:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. On the top bar, click on your account and under the Directory list, choose the Active Directory tenant where you wish to register your application.
3. Click on More Services in the left hand nav, and choose Azure Active Directory.
4. Click on `App registrations` and choose Add.
5. Enter a friendly name for the application, for example 'WebApp-OpenIDConnect-nodejs' and select 'Web Application and/or Web API' as the Application Type. For the sign-on URL, enter the base URL for the sample, which is by default http://localhost:3000/. Click on Create to create the application.
6. While still in the Azure portal, choose your application, click on `Settings` and choose `Reply URLs`. Add reply url :`http://localhost:3000/auth/openid/return` ,click Save button .
7. Find the Application ID value and copy it to the clipboard. Open `config.js` file in code sample , replace `clientID` with the Application ID value.
8. Setting `identityMetadata` with domain name or guid of tenant .
9. In the Azure portal, choose your application, click on `Settings` and choose `Keys`. Add a app key and copy to `clientSecret` in `config.js` .
10. Setting `useMongoDBSessionStore` to true if you want to use the mongoDB session store for session middleware , update  correct database url value to `exports.databaseUri .` Otherwise set `useMongoDBSessionStore` to false to use default session store .
11. Run the app. Use the following command in terminal: `node app.js` .
12. Open browser ,type `http://localhost:3000` and try your app .

Comment: (node:2628) DeprecationWarning: `open()` is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use `openUri()` instead, or set the `useMongoClient` option if using `connect()` or `createConnection()`. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#use-mongo-client

events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Nikunj Data\Project\Active ......................

Comment: For testing ,set exports.useMongoDBSessionStore in config.js to false, if you want to use the default session store for express-session.

Comment: I make it False and run with 'node app.js' but here cursor is blinking in second line, nothing appear here. neither Output nor Error now

Comment: 1. The mongoDB error means the mongodb server is not available , please check that . 2. after `node app.js`, open web browser , type `http://localhost:3000` to check whether the website is running .

Comment: Yes in localhost its show me "Welcome! Please log in."
and when I click on "Log In" nothing happends

Comment: Please confirm you have set identityMetadata/clientID/clientSecret correctly base on the app registered in AAD . Then using Fiddler or browser's developer tool to check whether any error return during the authorization process .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150924/discussion-between-nikunj-patel-and-nan-yu).

Comment: upv for Help but still issue there

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: I can now able to redirect on link of API after Authentication but not I am not clear what parameter I need to pass and from where I will get it.